# Jboss AS 7 Infinispan in clustered environment

Tags: jboss7.x, infinispan

I have an application deployed in Jboss AS 7 running on multiple nodes across different servers and I am trying to use infinispan 5.2 for caching data. The problem is that the cache value is not being replicated across different servers, it is accessible only from the same node.

The configuration used for caching is given here

```
<cache-container name="cluster" aliases="ha-partition" default-cache="cache" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/container/cluster">
            <transport lock-timeout="10000"/>
            <distributed-cache name="cache" mode="SYNC" start="EAGER" batching="false">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <eviction strategy="LIRS" max-entries="1000"/>
                <expiration lifespan="300000" />
            </distributed-cache>
        </cache-container>
```

I have also tried using replicated-cache instead of distributed-cache.

The tag  is defined in my web.xml.

Comment: Maybe the nodes are not forming a cluster? Check the log messages...

Comment: We are facing same issue with JBOS EAP 6.1. Did you find the reason?

Comment: Which _web.xml_ are you talking about? You mean _standalone.xml_ or _domain.xml_ and not _web.xml_ - right? Maybe the cluster nodes don't talk with eachother. Look for messages like "received new cluster view" in the _server.log_.

Answer (score 0):

I was with a problem like yours.

This [article](http://jboss-as-7-abhishekmathur.blogspot.in/2013/05/jboss-as-71-clustering.html) from Abhishek Mathur helped me to solve that.

I don´t know what type of data do you want to replicate, I want to replicate http session and the article work for me.